# PyInstaller bundle causes FileNotFoundError with multiprocessing spawn method

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pyinstaller, amazon-linux-2

I have a python application which is bundled using `pyinstaller --onefile` method. When running with multiprocessing start method `spwan`, it causes error in middle of the application.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web.py", line 1028, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 49, in _freeze_support
  File "multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
  File "multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 114, in _main
  File "multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
  File "multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
  File "runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
  File "runpy.py", line 231, in _get_code_from_file
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/_MEIRtGMqX/web.py'
[11797] Failed to execute script 'web' due to unhandled exception!
```

start method `fork` seems to be fine, but sometimes it hangs due to resource lock issue, so I prefer spawn. Does any one have any idea why this error occurs?

I have been using `freeze_support()` as mentioned in multiprocessing documentation even though it doesn't have any impact on Linux.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()
    set_start_method('spawn')
```

OS - Amazon linux 2

Python - 3.6.8

PyInstaller - 4.10

As I understood about `spwan`, It runs a new Python interpreter whenever creates a new process and tell it to import the main module and then execute. So my main module is `web.py`. So the error happens when a new process is created. But this issue is not consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for this problem is that the program cannot find web.py after packaging.
You can try adding the following code where you are using about path.

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    bundle_dir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    bundle_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

this code can help program find the file after packaging.
pyinstaller's document about this:https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But web.py is the main python file I have bundled using pyinstaller. Please let me know where should I use ```bundle_dir``` in the program in order to let program know about ```web.py``` path? I have a little confusion about it. Actually ```web.py``` has executed and in the middle of the application it throws this error. May be due to another process has been created using spawn method.

Comment: From the tracback, it seems that you use web.py in run.py line 261,  dis you use web.py as     a static file,like "python web.py" or with open("web.py")?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually ```runpy.py``` file is a python library file which executes the python scripts, It is not my custom python script. Link is here https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html

Answer (score 0):

At this point of time, Only one solution I have found is start the multiprocessing with method `forkserver`. I am not sure whether it leads to any hang in application.

`set_start_method('forkserver')`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when processes were spawned by threads. Using the "spawn" method from pyinstaller binaries on Linux is not thread-safe. If you are spawning processes concurrently from multiple threads, this issue can arise.

Follow https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/7410 for updates.

**UPDATE**

Per the [changelog](https://pyinstaller.org/en/v5.8.0/CHANGES.html#bugfix), a fix has been released in PyInstaller 5.8.0.

Comment: Please add context to your answer as link-only answers can become stale and may not help future users.  It is encouraged to provide links to source material, but providing only a link is discouraged.